# I am getting an error of invalid write of size 8 on my code when I run Valgrind

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I am also getting this message from Valgrind.

```
valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:280 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.
```

Here is my code if someone can test it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//creating the node structure
typedef struct node
{
    char first_name[45];
    struct node *next_node;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
    // creating the pointer list and setting it to NULL;
    node *list = NULL;
    char name[20];
    // creating the first node
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(n));
    if(n == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc cound't get enough mem.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // dereferencing the name in node and the next_node pointer in n
    printf("Please print the users first name\n");
    // getting user input and storing it in first name
    scanf("%s",n->first_name);

    n->next_node = NULL;
    // having list point at n the first node
    list = n;
    // creating the tempory pointer we will use to make the linked list in a loop
    node *temp = NULL;

    // generating a singly linked list with a loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        temp = n;
        n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(n == NULL)
        {
            printf("malloc wasn't able to allocate the memory we needed. Aborting the program\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //dereferencing the new n node
        printf("Please print the users first name\n");
        // getting user input on the name and storing it in the first name array
        scanf("%s",n->first_name);
        n->next_node = temp;
        list = n;
    }

    // looping through the linked list and printing out the values
    for(node*tmp = list; tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next_node)
    {
        printf("The name of the user is %s\n",tmp->first_name);

    }
    // freeing the linked list
    while(list!=NULL)
    {
        node *tempr = list->next_node;
        free(list);
        list = tempr;
    }

}
```

I am lost about how to fix this error. If anybody could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Build your program with debugging information. This is the `-g` flag to GCC or Clang. Then Valgrind will tell you exactly where your bug is.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("malloc cound't get enough mem.\n");` Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror("malloc could't get enough mem.");`  as the function: `perror()` is made to handle these two activities

Answer (score 3):

```
node *n = malloc(sizeof(n));
```

you are reserving space with the size of a pointer as argument (for sure not what you want), to reserve space with the size of the `struct` itself use:

```
node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
```

or

```
node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

as you are doing in the `for` loop.